# How to update the attributes of an object in the Photos library on Mac OS

Tags: macos, media, photos

Using the Media Library framework it's possible to have read-only access the attributes of a media object but you can't modify it.

Is there any way to write/update metadata attributes of the media objects so they are applied and accessible in the Photos app on Mac OS?